# how to cat all files containing string within a folder

Tags: bash

I am new to bash and hoping to get some advice..

I want to run a command in bash to `cat` all files that contain a specific string in a folder full of text files. Within these text files are unique codes, so it would be handy to run this query against the folder to look at all files with code `abc123` in it..

So something sort of like: `cat "abc123" | more`  ?

If I can achieve this without `cat` - happy to do that too..

Not sure if it's possible, any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
grep -l "abc123" * 2>/dev/null | xargs -d '\n' cat
```

- `grep -l <SOMETHING> *`: the -l option returns the filename of all files that contain the text SOMETHING.  `*` to check all files in the current directory.
- `2>/dev/null` is to suppress stdout on the `grep`.  The most classic message you get without it is "grep: DIRNAME: Is a directory".
- Pipe that to `xargs`, which takes the filenames from the grep output and apply the command `cat` to each.

**Update**: added `-d '\n'` to the `xargs` command to properly handle files with a space in their name.

Comment: or `cat $(grep -l "abc123" *)`

Comment: @PS. that suggestion breaks as soon as any file has a name containing a space or glob character.

Comment: ...and this one breaks in the (admittedly rare) case that a filename contains a newline - you can use `grep -lZ` and `xargs -0` to get around this issue.

Comment: @TomFenech This one breaks already when there are spaces in the filenames - which is not really seen rarely

Comment: @hek2mgl oops, that's right. I guess `xargs -d '\n'` would be a halfway fix, although better to go with the option I suggested previously if possible.

Comment: I would use the `find` command I've posted below. `xargs` is a dangerous (broken?) piece of software and should be really used with care.

Comment: Why "come on"? Just because you would never put a newline in a filename doesn't mean a script shouldn't be able to handle it.

Comment: 23 years in Unix / Linux, never seen that.  But theoretically sure, why not.

Comment: @Nic3500 Sure, newlines are not likely in normal filenames. But if you write programs which don't handle newlines in filenames correctly, users are able to pass input data beyond the specifications. Depending on the use case that can be a problem. Instead of spending time on thinking whether or not this can be a problem, I can just handle them correctly. Then it is definitely not a problem

Answer (score 2):

I would use `find`, like this:

```
find FOLDER -type f -exec grep -q 'abc123' {} \; -exec cat {} \;
```

Comment: This is safer than Nic3500's answer, as it allows all possible characters in filenames (including newlines).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments below [Nic2500's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51478285/2088135), the safe way to do this is to use:

```
grep -lZs "abc123" * | xargs -0 cat
```

`-Z` tells grep to output using a null byte instead of a newline as a separator. Since null bytes are not permitted in paths, this is the only safe way to pass lists of files between commands. `-s` suppresses "error messages about nonexistent or unreadable files", no need to redirect stderr (although I suppose that in principle, there could be other types of error messages generated by grep that you would want to redirect).

`-0` tells xargs that the list of arguments are separated by null bytes, so the output generated by `grep -Z` can be passed as a list of arguments to cat.

Using `find` also works, but the command in [hek2mgl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480966/2088135) calls a separate invocation of `grep` and `cat` for every file that is found, whereas the code in this answer calls one `grep` and as few `cat`s as are needed, taking into consideration the maximum length of a single command line.